# Can't find which method is being called by the button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, button

I am modifying the code of an ex-employe. I am pretty new to ASP.net and even web programming  and no comments was left inside the code.
In one of the forms, buttons are created dynamically and when one of the buttons are clicked on, a small form opens up with information.

Now my problem is I do not understand how the form is being opened.

This is where the buttons are created in `SuiviPlanFormation.aspx`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnComplete" runat ="server" Text ="B212"  
            CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("Code") %>' CommandName ="Select" 
            CssClass="button" 
            Enabled='<%# not Eval("Status").equals("green") %>'/>
```

And this is the form that seems to open when clicking on the B212 button `FormationForm.aspx`. The code obviously starts are the `Page_Load`.

I can't seem to figure out how that form is called. Can someone please enlighten me?

EDIT
`SuiviPlanFormation.aspx`

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="SuiviPlanFormation.aspx.vb" Inherits="SuiviPlanFormation" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/FormationForm.ascx" TagName ="FormationForm" TagPrefix ="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/SelectionForm.ascx" TagName ="SelectionForm" TagPrefix ="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Holder" Runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat ="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
            <cc1:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender ID="AlwaysVisibleControlExtender1" runat="server"
                  ScrollEffectDuration="0.1" HorizontalOffset="930" TargetControlID="pnlLegend"
                VerticalOffset="20">
            </cc1:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlLegend" runat="server"  Style="position : absolute ; visibility:visible  ; top:20px; left:930px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;"
                    width="420px">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="accordionHeaderSmall" colspan="2" style="border-style: none; padding-top: 2px;
                            padding-bottom: 2px">
                            Légende
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="texte" style="width: 5%; background-color: InfoBackground;
                            padding-left: 2px;">
                            <img alt="GREEN" height="10px" src="../Images/IconSystem/Indicateur/green.gif" width="10px" /></td>
                        <td class="texte" style="width: 95%; background-color: InfoBackground;" align="left">
                            Formation valide</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="texte" style="background-color: InfoBackground; padding-left: 2px;">
                            <img alt="Yellow" height="10px" src="../Images/IconSystem/Indicateur/Yellow.gif"
                                width="10px" /></td>
                        <td class="texte" style="background-color: InfoBackground;" align="left">
                            Formation non suivie, mais encore dans les délais de l'échéancier</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="texte" style="background-color: InfoBackground; padding-left: 2px;">
                            <img alt="RED" height="10px" src="../Images/IconSystem/Indicateur/red.gif" width="10px" /></td>
                        <td class="texte" style="background-color: InfoBackground;" align="left">
                            Formation invalide : Le délai de l'échéancier ou la nouvelle mise en vigueur est expiré</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="text-align: left; margin-left: 0; margin-top: 0;" width="98%" border="0">
    <tr style="height: 10px"><td colspan="2"></td></tr>    
        <tr>
            <td class="TexteSection" style="width:35%">
                <asp:Label ID="lbTitre" runat="server" CssClass="texteSection" Text="Plan de formation"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="right" style="width:65%">
                <asp:Label ID="lbMsgErreur" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"  
                    CssClass="msgerreur" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 1px">
            <td style="background-color: #F55443;" colspan="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" style="height:5px;"></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlFilter" runat="server" Visible="true">
                 <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding:5px;">
                    <tr><td colspan="4"  class="accordionHeader"  style="border-style:none;padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:2px" ><asp:Label CssClass=".grid .headerstyle" runat="server" ID="Label1">Filtre de sélection </asp:Label></td></tr>
                    <tr class="accordionContent" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                        <td class="popupcell02" align="left" width="200px" style="HEIGHT: 16px">Employé :</td>
                        <td width="200px" style="HEIGHT: 16px">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployes" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                 DataValueField ="NoEmploye" DataTextField ="FullName"  
                                DataSourceID="odsListEmployeesActif" ></asp:DropDownList></td>
                        <td class="popupcell02" align="left" style="padding-left:5px;" >
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTitre" runat="server" CssClass="popupcell02"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align ="right" >
                            Plan de formation version imprimable.

                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hylSuiviPlan" runat="server" ImageUrl ="/Apps/Images/Boutons/outils/imprimer.gif" Target ="_blank" />        

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="accordionContent" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                        <td class="popupcell02" align="left" >Type de document :</td>
                        <td >
                            <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlTypeDocument" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Text ="-" Value =""></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text ="Procédure" Value ="PROCÉDURE"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text ="Instruction" Value ="INSTRUCTION-JDE"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:dropdownlist>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right">
                            Attestation de formation en attente d'une approbation.
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hEnApprobation" runat="server" 
                                ImageUrl ="/Apps/Images/Boutons/outils/imprimer.gif" Target ="_blank" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="10px" ><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan ="2">


  <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlContainer" ScrollBars="Auto" Height="310px">
    <asp:GridView ID="dgFormation" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsListFormation" DataKeyNames="ID,DateMiseVigueurDoc"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="98%" AllowSorting="True" ShowHeader="true">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerFixestyle" />

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Code" SortExpression ="Code" >
                <ItemTemplate >

                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lkbDocument" runat ="server" Text ='<%# Eval("Code")  %>' Visible ='<%# GetNombreDocument(Container.DataItem) = 2 %>' onclick="lkbDocument_Click" CommandName ="Select"   ></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypDocument2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Code") %>' Enabled = '<%# GetNombreDocument(Container.DataItem) > 0 %>' Visible ='<%# GetNombreDocument(Container.DataItem) <> 2 %>' NavigateUrl='<%# GetDocumentUrl(Container.DataItem) %>' Target ="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>

                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCheminFichierFr" runat ="server" Value ='<%# Eval("CheminFichierFr") %>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCheminFichierEn" runat ="server" Value ='<%# Eval("CheminFichierEn") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                 <ItemStyle CssClass="texte" Width="10%" />                                             
                          <ControlStyle CssClass="texte" />             
            </asp:TemplateField> 

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Titre" SortExpression="Titre" HeaderText="Titre" HtmlEncode ="false"  >
                <ItemStyle CssClass="texte" Width="55%"/>
            </asp:BoundField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Lecture" SortExpression="Theorique" >
                <ItemTemplate  >
                    <center>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgTheorique" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Apps/images/Puces/Dark_check.gif" Visible ='<%# Eval("Theorique") %>'  />
                    </center>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="texte" Width="7%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Pratique"  SortExpression="Pratique">
                <ItemTemplate  >
                    <center>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Apps/images/Puces/Dark_check.gif" Visible ='<%# Eval("Pratique") %>' />
                    </center>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="texte" Width="7%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Statut" >
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <center >
                    <asp:Image ID="imgStatus" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Statut","../Images/IconSystem/Indicateur/{0}.gif") %>'  ToolTip ='<%# ToolTip(Container.DataItem) %>'/>
                    </center>                
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="texte" Width="5%"  />
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Formulaire" >
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <center >
                        <asp:Button ID="btnComplete" runat ="server" Text ="F-316"  
                            CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("Code") %>' CommandName ="Select" 
                            CssClass="button" Enabled='<%# not Eval("Statut").equals("green") %>'/>
                        </center>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="texte" Width="6%"/>
                <ControlStyle CssClass="texte" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate >
            Aucune donnée pour cette sélection
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
    </asp:Panel>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td></td><td align="right" style="height:25px" valign="bottom">
            <asp:Label ID="lbTotal" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>


            </td></tr>
    </table>

    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnTarget1" runat="server" Visible ="true" Width ="0px" Height ="0px" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnTarget2" runat="server" Visible ="true" Width ="0px" Height ="0px" />

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlFormation" runat ="server" Width ="25%" style="display:none;" >    
        <asp:FormView  ID="formViewFormation" runat="server" CellPadding="0" style="width:100%" DataSourceID="odsFormation" DefaultMode ="Insert"  >
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <uc1:FormationForm ID="ctrInsertFormation" runat="server" Formateur='<%# Bind("Formateur") %>'
                    But='<%# Bind("But") %>' Type='<%# Bind("Type") %>' Titre='<%# Eval("Titre") %>' Commentaire='<%# Bind("Commentaire") %>' />  
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
    </asp:Panel>

    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender X="300" Y="100" ID="modalInsertPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnTarget1" 
    PopupControlID="pnlFormation" BehaviorID="modalInsertPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"  >
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>   

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSelection" runat ="server" Width ="40%" style="display:none;" SkinID="modal" >    
        <uc1:SelectionForm  ID="ctrSelectionForm" runat ="server" CheminFichierFr ='<%# Eval("CheminFichierFr") %>' CheminFichierEn ='<%# Eval("CheminFichierEn") %>'     />
    </asp:Panel>

    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender X="400" Y="100" ID="modalSelectionForm" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnTarget2" 
    PopupControlID="pnlSelection" BehaviorID="modalSelectionForm" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"  >
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>   

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsListFormation" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetFormationsByEmploye" 
        TypeName="Ezem.BusinessObject.PlanFormationDB" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEmployes" Name="noEmploye" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull ="false" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlTypeDocument" Name="type" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull ="false"/>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsListEmployeesActif" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetListEmployeesActif" 
        TypeName="PersonnelDB">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

     <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsFormation" runat="server" 
         InsertMethod="InscrireFormation" 
         TypeName="Ezem.BusinessObject.PlanFormationDB" >
         <InsertParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dgFormation" Name="documentID" PropertyName="SelectedValue"  Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull ="false" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="nature" Type="String" DefaultValue ="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="autre" Type="String" DefaultValue ="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="formateur" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="but" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="commentaire" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEmployes" Name="noEmploye" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull ="false" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="approbateur" Type="String" DefaultValue ="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dateMiseVigueur" Type="DateTime" />
        </InsertParameters>


     </asp:ObjectDataSource>
         </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Content>
```

`SuiviPlanFormation.aspx.vb`

```
Imports System.Data
Imports Ezem.BusinessObject
Imports Utilitaires
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Partial Class SuiviPlanFormation
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Const SORT_ASC As String = " <span style='font-family: Webdings;font-size:8px '> 5</span>"
    Public Const SORT_DESC As String = " <span style='font-family: Webdings;font-size:8px '> 6</span>"

    Protected WithEvents ctrInsertFormationForm As Controls_FormationForm
    Protected WithEvents ctrInsertSelecForm As Controls_SelectionForm
    Private showDocument As Boolean = False
    Private approbateur As String

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ctrInsertFormationForm = formViewFormation.FindControl("ctrInsertFormation")

        If (Not IsPostBack) Then
            If (Utilitaires.IsInRole()) Then
                ddlEmployes.Enabled = True
            Else
                ddlEmployes.Enabled = False
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub odsListEmployeesActif_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles odsListEmployeesActif.Selected
        If (e.Exception IsNot Nothing) Then
            lbMsgErreur.Text = e.Exception.Message
            e.ExceptionHandled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub odsDocuments_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles odsFormation.Selected
        If (e.Exception IsNot Nothing) Then
            lbMsgErreur.Text = e.Exception.Message
            e.ExceptionHandled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub odsFormation_Inserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs) Handles odsFormation.Inserting
        If ctrInsertFormationForm.IsValide Then
            If (e.InputParameters("type").ToUpper() <> "LECTURE") Then
                Dim employe As New IEmploye(e.InputParameters("formateur"))

                e.InputParameters("approbateur") = employe.NoEmploye

                e.InputParameters("formateur") = employe.Fullname
                approbateur = e.InputParameters("approbateur")
                e.InputParameters("dateMiseVigueur") = CType(dgFormation.SelectedDataKey.Values(1), DateTime)
            Else
                e.InputParameters("dateMiseVigueur") = CType(dgFormation.SelectedDataKey.Values(1), DateTime)
                e.InputParameters("approbateur") = String.Empty
                e.InputParameters("formateur") = String.Empty
            End If
        Else
            e.Cancel = True
            lbMsgErreur.Text = "Erreur : Mauvais mot de passe!"
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub odsFormation_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles odsFormation.Inserted
        If (e.Exception IsNot Nothing) Then
            If (e.Exception.InnerException IsNot Nothing) Then
                lbMsgErreur.Text = e.Exception.InnerException.Message
            End If
            e.ExceptionHandled = True
        Else
            dgFormation.DataBind()
            If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(approbateur)) Then
                Try
                    Dim link As String = String.Format("{0}/Approbation.aspx", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LinkEnvironment"))
                    PersonnelDB.SendMailApprobation(approbateur, Session("NoEmploye"), ctrInsertFormationForm.Code & " - " & ctrInsertFormationForm.Titre, link)
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
                dgFormation.SelectedIndex = -1
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function ExistDocument(ByVal dataItem As Object) As Boolean
        Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(GetDocumentUrl(dataItem))
    End Function

    Public Function GetNombreDocument(ByVal dataItem As Object) As Integer
        Dim cheminFichierFr As String = String.Empty
        Dim cheminFichierEn As String = String.Empty

        If (Not DBNull.Value.Equals(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "CheminFichierFr"))) Then
            cheminFichierFr = DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "CheminFichierFr")
        End If

        If (Not DBNull.Value.Equals(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "CheminFichierEn"))) Then
            cheminFichierEn = DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "CheminFichierEn")
        End If

        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cheminFichierFr) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cheminFichierEn)) Then
            Return 2
        ElseIf (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cheminFichierFr)) Then
            Return 1
        ElseIf (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cheminFichierEn)) Then
            Return 1
        End If

        If (Not DBNull.Value.Equals(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "Type"))) Then
            If (CType(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "Type"), String).Trim.ToUpper = "INSTRUCTION-JDE") Then
                Return 1
            End If
        End If
        Return 0
    End Function

    Public Function GetDocumentUrl(ByVal dataItem As Object) As String
        Dim cheminFichierFr As String = String.Empty
        Dim cheminFichierEn As String = String.Empty

        If (Not DBNull.Value.Equals(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "CheminFichierFr"))) Then
            cheminFichierFr = DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "CheminFichierFr")
        End If

        If (Not DBNull.Value.Equals(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "CheminFichierEn"))) Then
            cheminFichierEn = DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "CheminFichierEn")
        End If

        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cheminFichierFr) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cheminFichierEn)) Then
            Return "javaScript:ShowPopUp('" & cheminFichierFr & "');"
        ElseIf (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cheminFichierFr)) Then
            Return cheminFichierFr
        ElseIf (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cheminFichierEn)) Then
            Return cheminFichierEn
        End If

        If (Not DBNull.Value.Equals(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "Type"))) Then
            If (CType(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "Type"), String).Trim.ToUpper = "INSTRUCTION-JDE") Then
                Return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PathUserGuide") & "=" & DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "Code")
            End If
        End If

        Return String.Empty
    End Function

    Protected Sub lkbDocument_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        showDocument = True
    End Sub

    Protected Sub dgFormation_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgFormation.SelectedIndexChanged
        If (showDocument) Then
            Dim hdfCheminFichierFr As HiddenField = dgFormation.SelectedRow.FindControl("hdfCheminFichierFr")
            Dim hdfCheminFichierEn As HiddenField = dgFormation.SelectedRow.FindControl("hdfCheminFichierEn")
            ctrSelectionForm.CheminFichierFr = hdfCheminFichierFr.Value
            ctrSelectionForm.CheminFichierEn = hdfCheminFichierEn.Value
            modalSelectionForm.Show()
            showDocument = False
        Else
            If (ctrInsertFormationForm IsNot Nothing) Then
                ctrInsertFormationForm.Reset()
            End If
            formViewFormation.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert)
            modalInsertPopup.Show()

            ctrInsertFormationForm.DocumentID = dgFormation.SelectedDataKey.Value
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function ToolTip(ByVal dataItem As Object) As String
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        Dim theorique As Object = DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "TypeTheorique")
        Dim pratique As Object = DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "TypePratique")
        Dim statut As String = CType(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "Statut"), String)


        Dim invalides As New List(Of String)
        If (Not DBNull.Value.Equals(theorique) AndAlso CType(theorique, Integer) = 1) Then
            invalides.Add("Lecture")
        End If

        If (Not DBNull.Value.Equals(pratique) AndAlso CType(pratique, Integer) = 1) Then
            invalides.Add("Pratique")
        End If
        If ("Yellow".Equals(statut)) Then
            result = CType(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "Echeancier"), DateTime).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

        ElseIf (invalides.Count = 0) Then
            result = "Valide"

        ElseIf (invalides.Count = 1) Then
            result = "Invalide: " & invalides(0)
        Else
            result = "Invalides: " & String.Join(",", invalides.ToArray())
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Protected Sub dgridDocuments_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgFormation.DataBound
        If (dgFormation.Rows.Count = 0) Then
            lbTotal.Text = String.Empty
        Else
            lbTotal.Text = "Nombre de documents : " & dgFormation.Rows.Count
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ddlEmployes_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlEmployes.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim emp As New IEmploye(ddlEmployes.SelectedValue)
        lblTitre.Text = emp.PosteTXT
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ddlEmployes_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlEmployes.DataBound

        ddlEmployes.SelectedValue = Session("NoEmploye")
        Dim employe As New IEmploye(ddlEmployes.SelectedValue)
        lblTitre.Text = employe.PosteTXT
    End Sub

    Protected Sub dgridDocuments_Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles dgFormation.Sorting
        Dim foundIndex As Short
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim sortDir As Long = -1
        If Not IsNothing(ViewState("sortDir")) Then sortDir = ViewState("sortDir")
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.SortExpression) Then
            For i = 0 To dgFormation.Columns.Count - 1
                dgFormation.Columns(i).HeaderText = dgFormation.Columns(i).HeaderText.Replace(SORT_ASC, String.Empty)
                dgFormation.Columns(i).HeaderText = dgFormation.Columns(i).HeaderText.Replace(SORT_DESC, String.Empty)
                If dgFormation.Columns(i).SortExpression = e.SortExpression Then
                    foundIndex = i
                End If
            Next
            If sortDir = SortDirection.Ascending Then
                dgFormation.Columns(foundIndex).HeaderText &= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(SORT_DESC)
                ViewState("sortDir") = SortDirection.Descending
                e.SortExpression &= " DESC"
            ElseIf sortDir = SortDirection.Descending Then
                dgFormation.Columns(foundIndex).HeaderText &= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(SORT_ASC)
                ViewState("sortDir") = SortDirection.Ascending
                e.SortExpression &= " ASC"
            Else
                If (foundIndex = 0) Then
                    dgFormation.Columns(0).HeaderText &= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(SORT_DESC)
                    ViewState("sortDir") = SortDirection.Descending
                    e.SortExpression &= " DESC"
                Else
                    dgFormation.Columns(foundIndex).HeaderText &= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(SORT_ASC)
                    ViewState("sortDir") = SortDirection.Ascending
                    e.SortExpression &= " ASC"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        If (Not IsPostBack) Then
            hylSuiviPlan.NavigateUrl = "PrintReports.aspx?CodeReport=SuiviPlan&NoEmploye=" & Session("NoEmploye") & "&Type="
            hEnApprobation.NavigateUrl = "PrintReports.aspx?CodeReport=EnApprobation&NoEmploye=" & Session("NoEmploye")
        Else
            hylSuiviPlan.NavigateUrl = "PrintReports.aspx?CodeReport=SuiviPlan&NoEmploye=" & ddlEmployes.SelectedValue & "&Type=" & ddlTypeDocument.SelectedValue
            hEnApprobation.NavigateUrl = "PrintReports.aspx?CodeReport=EnApprobation&NoEmploye=" & ddlEmployes.SelectedValue
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I don't seem to have a OnRowCommand

Comment: Post all of your markup and code-behind.

Comment: If you search thru code - does it reference `btnComplete` anywhere else?

Comment: nop, no reference to btn complete.

Comment: What about checking for `CommandName ="Select"` elsewhere?

Comment: @user2733242 - where is your code-behind? Also, is there any JavaScript or jQuery that could be handling the button click, either inline script or a script file reference?

Comment: I dont seem to see any inline script.  or script file reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called using the Handles statement in VB isn't it?

Protected Sub odsListEmployeesActif_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs) **Handles odsListEmployeesActif.Selected**

The button CommandName="Select" is a built in reserved call for GridView Commands and can also include "Update", "Edit", and "Cancel"

Comment: But I don't see how that Select opens up the FormationForm.aspx?

Comment: also I added a breakpoint there and when I do click on the button, it doesnt seem to enter that method

Comment: modalSelectionForm.Show() and modalInsertPopup.Show() might be the ticket, so you need to find the class file for modalInsertPopup, probably a .vb file by itself somewhere in directory. It was in the Protected Sub dgFormation_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgFormation.SelectedIndexChanged
 section. You should be able to right click on the .Show() portion and "Go to Definition"

Answer (score 0):

## Solution #1: Custom Server Controls

It looks like your friend has created a custom server control to provide this feature. Exhibit A:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlFormation" runat ="server" Width ="25%" style="display:none;" >    
        <asp:FormView  ID="formViewFormation" runat="server" CellPadding="0" style="width:100%" DataSourceID="odsFormation" DefaultMode ="Insert"  >
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <uc1:FormationForm ID="ctrInsertFormation" runat="server" Formateur='<%# Bind("Formateur") %>'
                    But='<%# Bind("But") %>' Type='<%# Bind("Type") %>' Titre='<%# Eval("Titre") %>' Commentaire='<%# Bind("Commentaire") %>' />  
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
    </asp:Panel>

    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender X="300" Y="100" ID="modalInsertPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnTarget1" 
    PopupControlID="pnlFormation" BehaviorID="modalInsertPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"  >
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>   

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSelection" runat ="server" Width ="40%" style="display:none;" SkinID="modal" >    
        <uc1:SelectionForm  ID="ctrSelectionForm" runat ="server" CheminFichierFr ='<%# Eval("CheminFichierFr") %>' CheminFichierEn ='<%# Eval("CheminFichierEn") %>'     />
    </asp:Panel>

    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender X="400" Y="100" ID="modalSelectionForm" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnTarget2" 
    PopupControlID="pnlSelection" BehaviorID="modalSelectionForm" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"  >
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

If you cannot rightly identify this code segment and its controls' tag prefixes, then it is most likely a custom control.

Unfortunately, these custom controls are normally developed separately from the web-project, and the compiled version is then loaded into the project. Additionally, the markup generated by server-side controls as well as their subroutines, functions, etc. are all located in the pre-compiled code-files.

---

Here are all my bookmarked links with info on custom asp.net controls. Good luck!

- [Create ASP.NET Server Controls from Scratch](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-asp-net-server-controls-from-scratch/)
- [A Crash Course on ASP.NET Control Development...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479311.aspx)
- [Creating Custom ASP.NET Server Controls with Embedded Javascript](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/04/29/creating-custom-asp-net-server-controls-with-embedded-javascript.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Embedding a JavaScript File as a Resource in an Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398930%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

---

## Solution #2

The only other thing I see is the modalInsertPopup in the code-behind. Try placing a breakpoint in this sub and see what happens.

```
Protected Sub dgFormation_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgFormation.SelectedIndexChanged
        If (showDocument) Then
            Dim hdfCheminFichierFr As HiddenField = dgFormation.SelectedRow.FindControl("hdfCheminFichierFr")
            Dim hdfCheminFichierEn As HiddenField = dgFormation.SelectedRow.FindControl("hdfCheminFichierEn")
            ctrSelectionForm.CheminFichierFr = hdfCheminFichierFr.Value
            ctrSelectionForm.CheminFichierEn = hdfCheminFichierEn.Value
            modalSelectionForm.Show()
            showDocument = False
        Else
            If (ctrInsertFormationForm IsNot Nothing) Then
                ctrInsertFormationForm.Reset()
            End If
            formViewFormation.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert)
            modalInsertPopup.Show()

            ctrInsertFormationForm.DocumentID = dgFormation.SelectedDataKey.Value
        End If
    End Sub
```

---

I also wanted to address your comment

> The code obviously starts are the Page_Load.

This is not always the case. There are several stages in the life-cycle of an ASP.NET webforms page. You can check out [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview - MSDN - Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28VS.100%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I tried putting a breakpoint there, but to no avail.

I'll check out the Page_Load of FormationForm.ascx ( I did put a breakpoint there and it does go thru it, i'm just not sure how it reaches here)